# Personalize Copy As LaTeX

Tags: latex

Built-in functions in formulas copied as $\LaTeX$ code from output cells are sometimes messy. I'd like to find a way to simplify the way this code is generated.

There is one concrete instance that I'd like to raise:

**"Conjugate" is an exponent of blank, and adds brackets**: The expression $g_1^* g_2$, which produces `Out: Conjugate[Subscript[g, 1]] Subscript[g, 2]` is copied as

```
g_2 \left(g_1\right){}^*
```

There is no need to use parentheses, or the exponent of blank. All this extra code just makes the expression more cluttered.

How can I personalize the way "Conjugate" is translated to Latex? My expected output would be "g_1^* g_2"

Comment: You are looking for customizing the output of TeXForm. There have been questions on this in the past, and you can find solutions like this one: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/180460/12 Unfortunately, TeXForm does not officially support customization, so solutions you find here may not be fully robust or may break in future versions.

Comment: Another one: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47417/format-and-texform-does-not-work-as-expected

Answer (score 5):

As discussed in my previous posts about [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm), you can achieve your goal by giving custom formats for symbols in question. To do this, it is convenient to make use of my [Initial](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/153885/45431) function to redefine an internal function:

```
Initial[Convert`TeX`ExpressionToTeX] /: 
    Convert`TeX`ExpressionToTeX[e__] /; !TrueQ@$TeX := Block[
        {$TeX = True},
        Convert`TeX`ExpressionToTeX[e]
    ]
```

Now, any `TEX` conditioned [`FormatValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FormatValues) will be used if defined. Next, we give [`Conjugate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Conjugate) a [`FormatValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FormatValues) to do what you want:

```
Initial[Conjugate] /: 
    MakeBoxes[Conjugate[Subscript[g_,a_]], TraditionalForm] /; $TeX := SubsuperscriptBox[
        MakeBoxes[g, TraditionalForm],
        MakeBoxes[a, TraditionalForm],
        "*"
    ]
```

Check:

```
Conjugate[Subscript[g, 1]] Subscript[g, 2] //TeXForm
```

> g_1^* g_2

For more details see my answers to [is it possible to change/customize some conversions done by TeXForm?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/153891/45431) and [Multiplication sign in TeXForm?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/180949/45431).

Answer (score 2):

There obviously isn't a plain way to do this. Except to make your own solution. Reprocess your LaTeX strings with FireMath or MathType. Or work it by hand, manage your clipboard. Create Gists on GitHub and copy/paste from them, as needed.

Get into the habit of knowing your math LTX and hand edit it. I still do, most of the time. Sorry, I can't give a better answer. (*) Unless, try //TraditionalForm, before the //TeXForm